# QTimer slot doesn't get called

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtimer

I have a `QTimer` in `MainWindow` class but the `update` slot doesn't get called. I'm new to QT. I have no idea what it would be. `connect()` return `true` and I get neither warning from messages window in QT creator nor run-time errors. It just doesn't work.

```
void MainWindow::on_startBtn_clicked()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    qDebug() << connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(500);
}

void MainWindow::update()
{
    qDebug() << "update() called";
}
```

Comment: And you should not override standard http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update QWidget::update but should call your own slot some other name. QMainWindow is QWidget.

Comment: does `MainWindow::on_startBtn_clicked()` get called when you click on startBtn button?

Comment: My guess would be that MainWindow is missing the Q_OBJECT macro and thus QWidget::update() is called

Comment: @AlexanderVX: Thanks,l I renamed the method name.

Comment: @ahmed: Yes, it does. The issue was somewhere else

Comment: This question should be closed: it doesn't provide enough code to reproduce the problem, and it is a simple typo style of an issue. Any answers are unlikely to be useful to anyone, neither is the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided is valid. I just tried it in an empty default GUI Qt project.

Header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_startBtn_clicked();
    void update();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Implentation:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_startBtn_clicked()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    qDebug() << connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(500);
}

void MainWindow::update()
{
    qDebug() << "update() called";
}
```

And the result:

```
Démarrage de E:\projects\playground\build-qt_gui_test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\qt_gui_test.exe...
true
update() called
update() called
update() called
update() called
update() called
update() called
update() called
E:\projects\playground\build-qt_gui_test-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\qt_gui_test.exe s'est terminé avec le code 0
```

Please verify that the update() method is declared in your header, as a slot. Check that you didn't forget Q_OBJECT macro, you included required classes. The issue probably come from something you didn't show in your question.

Comment: It's a shame, when I moved the code to new class to make a small test case I forget to declare the method as slot

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. 
Just make sure that the function that you call ( myUpdate() ) 
is in slot declaration in the header file

for example:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event);

    //void myUpdate();  // <------          NEVER PUT INHERE
public slots:           // <------          MUST BE IN HERE
    void myUpdate();    // <------
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Comment: widgets have a method called [update()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) so it is advisable to use another name because it can bring you problems.

Comment: Thanks eyllanese. I changed the name to myUpdate() instead.

Comment: On the other hand, a function other than a slot can also be connected with the new connection syntax.